# Django & PayPal integration

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am designing a website in Python (using Django), and I need to sell things through it.

Can somebody help me with the source code to integrate the paypal-pro (do-direct payment) or else paypal-standard (express checkout)?

Answer (score 29):

You might want to try [django-paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal), there's even a [tutorial](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html) right there on the front page.

Comment: You sir, are a saint... +1 for the service you've done the community in editing the question :)

Comment: i can't see tutorial there :(

Comment: How to use `express checkout` ? Right now only `website payment pro(wpp)` is working and it throws error as wpp is available in selected countries.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger kindly take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955000/not-getting-django-paypal-ipn-handshake

Answer (score 13):

### [paypal.standard.ipn](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

PayPal API Generates a Button which will call its API through `paypal.standard.ipn`.

For API Integration you have to follow below given steps:

Install `django-paypal`:

```
pip install django-paypal
```

Update **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'paypal.standard.ipn',
]

PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL = 'XXXXX'
PAYPAL_TEST = True
```

Write Email address of Receiver. `PAYPAL_TEST = True` means you want a Test API payment. You can write  "False" for Original payment API.

Run command:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

In **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
url(r'^payment_process/$', api_views.payment_process, name='payment_process' ),
url(r'^payment_done/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name= "pets/payment_done.html"), name='payment_done'),
url(r'^payment_canceled/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name= "pets/payment_canceled.html"), name='payment_canceled'),*
```

In **views.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm


def payment_process(request):
    host = request.get_host()
    paypal_dict = {
        'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        'amount': '100',
        'item_name': 'Item_Name_xyz',
        'invoice': 'Test Payment Invoice',
        'currency_code': 'USD',
        'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        'return_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('payment_done')),
        'cancel_return': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse('payment_canceled')),
    }
    form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
    return render(request, 'pets/payment_process.html', {'form': form})
```

[Follow video tutorial for django-code given in reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5dBopZWOzo&t=417s)

In **payment_process.html**:

```
{{ form.render }}
```

For calling API you have request for `/payment_process/`. It will generate a button on HTML which calls PayPal API for transaction. Further process will be done on PayPal end, Login or Card Payment.

Comment: Can you please elaborate following code because I am new on django . you used pets/....... what is pets ? is it your app or generic app ?url(r'^paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),
url(r'^payment_process/$', api_views.payment_process, name='payment_process' ),
url(r'^payment_done/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name= "pets/payment_done.html"), name='payment_done'),
url(r'^payment_canceled/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name= "pets/payment_canceled.html"), name='payment_canceled'),*

Comment: @SatinderSingh, "pets" is a Django app which is the main app in this project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply . Can we customize that button like its color or size etc . Can you give me some idea .

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at [pypaypal](http://code.google.com/p/pypaypal/)? You could create a view that connects to PayPal and submit your payment commands.

Comment: Can we send payments from a paypal personal account? All the blogs and tutorials that I have seen shows it on business account.

Answer (score 1):

Better will be to use "native" docs from owner: [docs paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://dev.to/abderrahmanemustapha/paypal-payments-and-django-client-server-side-basics-9l8) guides how to accept Paypal apps payment via sandbox `ClientId` & `SecretKey` without any third party library.

You can also send payment tracking id as `custom_id` in `purchase_units` list's dictionary  object to `create_order.request_body` function.
As shown below:

```
create_order.request_body (
        {
            "intent": "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units": [
                {
                    "custom_id": "YOUR_TRACKING_ID",
                    "amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": course.price,
                        "breakdown": {
                            "item_total": {
                                "currency_code": "USD",
                                "value": course.price
                            }
                            },
                        },                               


                }
            ]
        }
    )
```