# Payment options with Django

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am trying to make a real time e-commerce site that people can really order stuff on. I wanted it to have an actual payment option like Stripe. But is there any other option other than Stripe? Can I use something like Payoneer, or PayPal or something like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714284/django-paypal-integration There you go

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. But do you have any ideas for Payoneer??

Comment: You can use their API. You shall find it by googling

Comment: The above information for using PayPal with Django is old; a current HTML+JS PayPal integration is documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/  and can be adapted to any framework

Answer (score 1):

A [current HTML+JS PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) can be adapted to any framework, but [here is a Django-specific guide](https://abderrahmane.hashnode.dev/the-basics-of-adding-paypal-payments-to-django-server-and-client-side).